# iOS: App size after adding C++ static library is too big?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, static-libraries

I'm making a game using some C++ static libraries (`.a` files).

After building completed, i see Xcode copies these libraries to the build folder (DerivedData) and some of them have size = 600mb (`libcocos2d iOS.a` - cocos2d-x)

So i wonder what my app actual size will be on the store, it is ipa file + static libraries?

Or how XCode compiler works with those static libraries?

Answer (score 1):

To see the actual size, archive the product and check it in the organizer.

Debug builds produce much larger products.

I have seen 35 MB libraries go down to 10 MB when building release, but your mileage may vary.